# Сравнить данные из input и data-attr

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть данные которые мы передаем в атрибут, в таком виде data-date=" 28.06.2018 28.06.2018 29.09.2018"

И есть input c datepicker, вопрос в том, как сделать проверку на совпадение даты из инпута с любой из указанных дат внутри атрибута.

Сейчас код выглядит так, понимаю что такое условие здесь точно не подходит, но не могу сообразить как его нужно записать:

```
                    $('.date-filter').on('change', function(){
                        var dateFilter = $('#date-filter').val();

                            $('.item').each(function() {
                              if(dateFilter === $(this).attr('data-date').split(' ')){

                              } else{

                              }
                            });
                    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если формат в datepicker такой же как и дат в data-date, то разбиваете по пробелу на массив и ищите совпадение в массиве

Т.е. как-то так:

```
var $this_input = $('.this_input');
    all_date = $this_input.attr('data-date').split(' ')

$this_input.on('change', function(){
  console.log(all_date.indexOf($(this).val()))
})
```

Comment: Формат такой же, но что-то применить ваш код не удалось, у меня слега иначе все это записано, добавил свой код в вопрос

Comment: Что такое $('.item')  и зачем вы его в цикле гоните ?

Comment: Много таких элементов на странице и нужно каждый проверить на совпадение с датой

Comment: $(this).attr('data-date').split(' ').indexOf(dateFilter)

Comment: Вы берёте дату(строку) и сравниваете с массивом. А вам нужно искать в массиве элемент на совпадение

Comment: Разобрался, теперь понял, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял есть одинаковый формат дат и стоит найти одинаковое. Возможно просто загнать их в JSON и сравнить как строки. Например вот так

```
var dateFilter = JSON.stringify($('#date-filter').val());
$('.item').each(function() {
     var tmp_formed = JSON.stringify($(this).attr('data-date'));
        if (dateFilter.localeCompare(tmp_formed) !==0){какой-то код}
}
```

Comment: Решил попробовать, но в таком виде у меня не отработало

Comment: Результат условия всегда "1" получается

Comment: поясните, пожалуйста, почему результат 1.  Результат localeCompare -1, 0, 1, где 0 это равные строки [ссылка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/62b7ahzy(v=vs.94).aspx). По несработке, возможно формирование data- идет с добавлением пробелов или разные механизмы, тогда конечно не сработает. Я так вообще массивы сравнивал

Comment: Там пробелы в конце каждого значения (data-date="28.06.2018 28.06.2018 29.09.2018 "), а форматы дат совпадают точно

Comment: попробуйте, перед сравнением trim() использовать, он откинет лишние пробелы по краям. Хм, сейчас понял, в data-date находятся строки, тогда просто trim() и сразу localeCompare

Comment: Извините, мой метод не будет работать. Суть задачи уяснил не правильно. У вас есть data-date="28.06.2018 28.06.2018 29.09.2018 "  где хранятся эталоны по которым сравнивается другое, тогда стоит  рассмотреть другой механизм, например вложенный for() c данным списком, превращенным в массив join(' ')